# How to get directed graph by dot

Tags: linux, dot

When i test this undirected graph is normal:

```
graph test{
A -- B
}
```

But When i test

```
graph test{
A -> B
}
```

It report this

> Error: call-graph2018-08-06.dot: syntax error in line 2 near '->'

I follow this link:

[DOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language))

Comment: it says: "The syntax is the same as for undirected graphs, except the `digraph` keyword is used to begin the graph". have you tried using `digraph` instead?

Comment: It works!Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness and posterity, I thought I'd add an answer here.

You need to start your program with the `digraph` keyword:

```
digraph test{
A -> B
}
```

This will allow the engine to process `->` tokens as directional edges.